# Question about constructor set-up that contains an array

Tags: java

The parameters of the constructor are: nPlayers

I am trying to create a playerHand array of size [nPlayers][CARDS_IN_DECK]

How would I assign the playerHand in order to successfully create an array of size [nPlayers][CARDS_IN_DECK].

Comment: Could you add some of your code, please?

Comment: even if your code isn't working / done, it's much better to see actual code instead of reading a description of it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code will be create a class and initialize your like below in constructor

```
public class Cards {

private int numberOfCards;
private int numberOfPlayers;
private int[][] deck;
public Cards(int numberOfPlayers, int numberOfCards){
     this.numberOfCards = numberOfCards;
     this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
     this.deck = new int[numberOfPlayers][numberOfCards]
   }
  // other getters and setters here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing a LOT of information but an example would be something like:

```
public class MyObject {
    private static final int CARDS_IN_DECK = 52;
    private SomeObject[][] myArray;

    public MyObject(int nPlayers) {
        this.myArray = new SomeObject[nPlayers][CARDS_IN_DECK];
    }
}
```